# POM not released using Jenkins and Artifactory Release

Tags: jenkins, gradle, artifactory

We're trying to use the Artifactory release process in Jenkins to publish a `jar` file created by a Gradle build into a Maven repo in our Artifactory server.

It nearly all works, the only issue is that the `pom` file isn't being copied into the Artifactory repo.

The Gradle build includes the Gradle Maven plugin and running `gradlew install` locally results in both the `jar` and the `pom` inserted into the local Maven repo.

I've added a task in the Gradle build that generates the `pom` file in the same directory as the `jar` file and changed the Jenkins build to run that task too.

When the build has completed I can see both the `jar` and the `pom` file in the workspace.

Any ideas on what I need to do to get the `pom` file published along with the `jar`?

We're using:

- Jenkins 2.10
- Artifactory plugin 2.4.4
- Gradle 2.14

The Gradle build file does not inlcude the Gradle Artifactory plugin.

Cheers, Andy

The Jenkins project is configured to use the Gradle-Artifactory integration (rather than the Generic-Artifactory integration).

Comment: Do you have any screenshots of the Artifactory upload section of your job? Might give some more insight

Comment: I realised that in addition to having the artifactory integration enabled, I also had the Maven 3 integration box ticked... Unticking maven3 means that everything now works as expected.

Comment: Post as an answer and accept it :) Glad it's working

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Dakota Brown I'm answering my own question, the solution to my problem was to un-tick the maven3 integration option. With that option unslected, everything works as expected.